# Tablet vs phone detection with 51degrees.mobi

Tags: c#, detection, tablet

I am trying to find a way to determine a mobile device as a phone or a tablet. I am using the C# library by 51Degree.mobi (http://51degrees.codeplex.com/). I see that the there is already a IsMobileDevice property on the Browser object so I know whether it is a mobile device or not but now I am looking for another property IsTablet (or some other way to figure out that). I suppose I can base that decision on the screen size, but that doesn't seem solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's configurable within your web.config. You would use the is_tablet check and write something like:

```
<location name="tablet" url="/Tablet/Tablet.aspx">
   <add property="is_tablet" matchExpression="true"/>
</location>
```

See: http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Documentation/Foundation/UserGuide.aspx for their complete guide.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I need to access this value at runtime from withing C# code. So I think I will have to do something like Request.Browser["is_tablet"]...That should work.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone stumbling across this in the future, it may be worth bearing in mind that the current (March 2012) version doesn't expose a `IsTabletDevice` property unless you have the premium version.

Reference: http://51degrees.mobi/Products/DeviceData/PropertyDictionary.aspx